# How to hide the status bar in some of the activities inside a tab activity on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application with three tabs. I am using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to hide the status bar. It works when I put it inside my `TabActivty` in the manifest. This will hide the status bar in all of the three activities (inside the `TabActivity`). I want to hide the status bar for two of the three activities, not all of them. When I try to use the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` for each `Activity` in the manifest, it won't hide the status bar.
How can I hide the status bar for just some of the activites inside the `TabActivity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code in each activity want to hide status bar.

```
   public void onResume()
   {
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }, 1500);  
   }
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong though.

Comment: Where should I create the handler? I am creating it inside `onResume()`, but it still does not work for me.

Comment: This works! 1500ms gave me a delay in my UI that did not look good. I changed the time to 100ms and it still works without any noticeable difference to the UI.

Comment: I am not able to confirm this or not, but since a user have had luck with this answer, I am going to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You have set Theme for your activity in android manifest as follows...

```
<activity android:name=".Login" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Please verify your activity tag after editing it.

Comment: This will only hide the title bar though, not the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can call `getActionBar().hide()` or `getSupportActionBar().hide()`. This should allow you to show and hide the action bar as required. If you are trying to do this inside the fragments the you may need to get a reference the FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following trick

```
<activity android:name=".Login" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```